# How to select rows and replace some columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'A': [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4], 'B': [9, 2, 5, 3], 'C': [0, 0, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df
```

If I have data like below

```
     A  B   C
0   NaN 9   0
1   4.0 2   0
2   NaN 5   5
3   4.0 3   3
```

I want to select the raw that column A is `NaN` and replace column B's value with np.nan as follows.

```
    A   B   C
0   NaN NaN 0
1   4.0 2.0 0
2   NaN NaN 5
3   4.0 3.0 3
```

I tried to do `df[df.A.isna()]["B"]=np.nan`, but it didn't work.
According to [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), I should to select data by `df.iloc`.  But the problem is that if df have numerous rows, I can't select data by input index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
You were pretty close actually. Use `pd.Series.isnull` on `A` and assign values to `B` using `df.loc`:

```
df.loc[df.A.isnull(), 'B'] = np.nan
df

     A    B  C
0  NaN  NaN  0
1  4.0  2.0  0
2  NaN  NaN  5
3  4.0  3.0  3
```

---

**Option 2**
`np.where`:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df.A.isnull(), np.nan, df.B)
df

     A    B  C
0  NaN  NaN  0
1  4.0  2.0  0
2  NaN  NaN  5
3  4.0  3.0  3
```

Comment: `df.loc` is the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with inverted condition - by default replaced to `NaN`s:

```
df['B'] = df.B.mask(df.A.isnull())
```

---

```
df['B'] = df.B.where(df.A.notnull())
```

Very similar is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) - define both outputs:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df.A.isnull(), np.nan, df.B)
```

---

```
print (df)
     A    B  C
0  NaN  NaN  0
1  4.0  2.0  0
2  NaN  NaN  5
3  4.0  3.0  3
```

**Timings**:

```
dic = {'A': [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 4], 'B': [9, 2, 5, 3], 'C': [0, 0, 5, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [61]: %timeit df['B'] = np.where(df.A.isnull(), np.nan, df.B)
The slowest run took 7.57 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 405 µs per loop

In [62]: %timeit df['B'] = df.B.mask(df.A.isnull())
The slowest run took 70.14 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 3.54 ms per loop

In [63]: %timeit df['B'] = df.B.where(df.A.notnull())
The slowest run took 5.65 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit df.B += df.A * 0
The slowest run took 12.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 913 µs per loop

In [67]: %timeit df.loc[df.A.isnull(), 'B'] = np.nan
The slowest run took 4.56 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the timings! (and +1).

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I think `df.loc[df.A.isnull(), 'B'] = np.nan` is more readable.

Comment: @Dawei - For me personally is more readable `mask` or `np.where` ;) But al solutions working nice, so it is up to you what solution use ;)

Answer (score 5):

Because my counterparts took the logical choices...

```
df.B += df.A * 0
df

     A    B  C
0  NaN  NaN  0
1  4.0  2.0  0
2  NaN  NaN  5
3  4.0  3.0  3
```

Comment: Interesting solution ;)

Comment: I seem to be a bit playful tonight (-:

Comment: Uh-may-zing...!

Comment: This is a clever whimsical answer.  Both of the other answers need another upvote in order for the community to understand their worthiness.